# Self-taught wanting to clean up (Packages, structure, best practices...)

Tags: actionscript-3, class, directory, package, naming

First off I apologize for the slightly vague question.

I'm a self-taught coder and the more I work, the more I find myself wanting to invest in the whole process (and God knows there is room for improvement).

I'm looking for very "basic" material (books recommendation if you can!) about things like how to structure code and comments to make things clear, how to structure a project directory (How far should I divide my stuff into packages? How to properly name classes, subclasses, make it all understandable and clear?), this kind of stuff. Not the actual *how make things work*, but rather *how to make things clean, understandable and well structured*.

I've been reading a lot on design patterns, good software design and things like that, but **there is this "gap" in my knowledge where I can think of a good solution to my problems, but the *execution itself* is pretty messy and ugly.**

I've always worked solo, and chances are I will soon be working with other coders on my projects. Right now I sometimes have trouble understanding my own code, so there is no way others could dive in and help me.

I'm coding in AS 3.0, should anyone wonder.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Careful a little is a good thing but to much methodology can be very styfling.

Comment: This question isn't really appropriate for StackOverflow (because it is so vague and there isn't really a correct answer), but ... I would recommend Code Complete by Steve McConnell. It addresses a lot of what you are asking about. It has no Actionscript, but lots of great advice that applies to all languages. For more Actionscript-specific advice, try Essential Actionscript by Colin Moock.

Comment: Thanks bwroga, I feared as much but didn't really know where to ask! Code Complete has been suggested to me a few times and I think it would be a very good starting point, so I'll definitely try to get my hands on this.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how new you are to coding, I'd recommend looking into why 'encapsulation' makes sense.
When I was new to object oriented programming I couldn't understand the appeal of encapsulation, but now I see how it really can help keep your code 'clean' - and I strongly suspect it's fundamental to a lot of other object oriented concepts; Design patterns, avoiding 'tight coupling', composition, code reuse and so on.
Here's the wiki info on encapsulation...
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)
..but here's my summary:

I've heard the analogy of a car used: The user doesn't need to know HOW the engine works; they just need to know that, when they turn the key, the engine WORKS. Encapsulation keeps the implementation of a class's methods secret. The methods themselves are public (to be accessible outside the class) but properties are private.

By making properties private and limiting the number of public-facing methods in your classes you can have your classes operate as independently as possible. It also means you can totally change HOW a method is implemented inside a class (so long as it retains the same name and argument signature) without anyone OUTSIDE of that class needing to know anything about it. Even if that 'anyone' is YOU it can still really speed up development because you're not having to track down multiple references to public variables of the class throughout your code.

So AIM to have your classes perform one function; Think about if a method would, in fact, be better 'hidden away' in another class. Even if you have multiple objects instantiated 'inside' another, your code will be much more clean and you can be more sure about WHERE that specific piece of code you're searching for is - if a class mostly has one function, it's easier to remember what it does.

Other than that, I'd also recommend using only shallow inheritance; Having a complex hierarchy of classes and subclasses can lead to objects that need to inherit from more than one class. Look into 'composition' and interfaces too. (Interfaces are kind of AS3's solution to not having multiple inheritance).